# Bilinear covariants of Dirac field

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

In the book "Advanced quantum mechanics" by Sakurai there is a section (3.5) about bilinear covariants, however i can't really find a definition of these objects, neither in the book nor online. I'm particularly interested in the point where the author states that the 5 listed bilinear covariants exhaust all the possible bilinear covariants of the form $\overline{\psi}\;\Gamma\;\psi$, where $\Gamma$ is a complex 4x4 matrix and $\psi$ the Dirac wave function. What does this means? It means that it's not possible to obtain other bilinear covariants or that we can somehow combine them to obtain other ones? In addition, the way the author deal with these covariants seems to suggest that he considers as bilinear covariants not the 16 bilinear forms listed, but rather the 5 groups of bilinear forms with covariant transformation properties. In turn, this fact suggest that saying that it is not possible to find other bilinear covariants than the one listed means we can't find other bilinear forms and group them in such a way to obtain covariant tensors of any rank. Does what i'm saying even make sense?

[image]

The image attached show the bilinear covariants I'm referring in the previous text. The $\gamma_\mu$ are the Dirac matrices and $\sigma_{\mu\nu}=-\frac{i}{2}[\gamma_\mu,\gamma_\nu]$, $\gamma_5=\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\gamma_0$.

Comment: You appreciate that any 4x4 complex matrix can be represented as a linear combination of these 16 basis matrices, and specify the equivalence of all Clifford algebra representations in 4d: Pauli's fundamental theorem, no?

Comment: Yes, i thought it has something to do with the fact that those 16 matrices are a basis, but i still don't get how this implies that I can't find another different bilinear covariants, since I don't find anywhere the definition of bilinear covariants and plus, even if I can write $\Gamma$ as a linear combination of the 16 matrices, what would prevent me from finding, for example, other 4 matrices $\beta_\nu$ different from $\gamma_\mu$ such that $\overline{\psi}\;\beta_\nu\;\psi$ is another different covariant vector?

Comment: It's all about linear dependence and choice of basis. Your 4 matrices $\beta_\nu$ might obey the Cliffords algebra, in which case Pauli's theorem dictates that they be a similarity transform of the γ s, or else can be written as a linear combination of some of the 16 matrices discussed...